# Make Cygwin installer `setup.exe` authenticate with username and password for proxy automatically

Tags: cygwin

There is `--proxy` option for Cygwin installer `setup.exe`, but it only accepts `address:port`.

**How to provide username and password if the proxy requires authentication *unattendedly*?**

In manual scenario, Cygwin installer is able to prompt for username and password. I want to avoid this in automated scenario. All I noticed on the Internet is [authentication is possible](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2000-08/msg00929.html), however, I believe this is about manual scenario.

NOTE: This is NOT the case when I want to [provide command line tools with proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5807110/441652).

Answer (score 0):

There are automation tools for windows that will interface with the gui provided by setup.exe if you cannot get it to authenticate from the command line.

I can't recommend any specific application as I don't use them but I've been aware of the concept forever.

Google returns many results

https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=windows+automation+tools